# How to use multiple subprocess in python without freezing the tkinter window (mainloop)?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, subprocess

I have 2 subprocess that calls ffmpeg in a tkinter program, both subprocesses are linked to each other. But when I start the processes normally then the main tkinter window become unresponsive and freezes until the subprocesses end. I used threading so that the tkinter window is not affected but in that case the second subprocess starts immediately killing the old subprocess without waiting. How can I fix this?

Here is how I used the threading:

```py
def process():        
            subprocess.Popen(f'"{ffmpeg}"-i "{inputpath}" {parameters} -y "{outputpath}"', shell=True)
thread = threading.Thread(target=process)
thread.start()
```

What I want is to run the subprocesses in background in one sequence (means the second subprocess should run only after completing the first one) and also without freezing the main tkinter window.

Comment: Your code is not enough to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Move both subprocesses into same thread.